# dynamic dropdown for form

Tags: asp.net, vbscript

I am creating a 1 dropdown list that have 2 options which it Window and Linux. Before user select anything, the forms are "hidden" or not exist until user is select one of options. If the user select Window, the Window form will show up to fill it out. If the user select Linux, the Linux form will show up as well. I am using a vb and can anyone give me a small example or a link of example that is pretty close to this? Do I have to dynamically create a form in vb script or the html is fine?

Here my sample codes so far,

asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content1" Runat="Server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListForm" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Window</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Linux</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id = Window>
             Form info....
        </div>
        <div id = Linux>

         Form info....
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Small point to note for future questions vb.net <> vbscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with javascript by making an event that will triger on select item in your drop down list. After you select item then you can make your own logic to display desired view s.

Take a look at this: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Comment: Also I would suggest  you to take a look at asp.net mvc or spa, they are far more client friendly than standard asp.net webforms.